# SMTP Authentication using C#

Tags: c#, email, smtp

i want to send email by c# desktop application, user can send by default email using this code

```
SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
mail.From = new MailAddress("email@gmail.com", "Display Name");
mail.To.Add(EmailTo.Text.Trim());
mail.Subject = EmailSubject.Text;
mail.Body = EmailText.Text;
System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;
attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(file);
mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);
SmtpServer.Port = 587;
SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("email@gmail.com", "Password");
SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
```

and its working great. But i want to give the user to manual set his SMTP settings so I will let him enter his server name, user name and password for his email address but how can i use his SMTP server user name and password ? and what else do i need to make this happens ????

Answer (score 0):

Whats the issue in doing it?

Update your code and pull value from app.config,
once user enters new value, then update app.config

and you are good to go

Comment: thnx for replaying, i have to use it here because i am using c# WinForm application

Comment: thats ok, you can store these values in app.config and update it for the same whenever needed